# Edge (Chromium版) を使用してwindow.open()を実施した際に、別ウィンドウで表示させたい

Tags: javascript

以下のプログラムをEdge (Chromium版) で開き「新たにウィンドウを開く」ボタンを押すと新しい画面が別ウィンドウで表示する事が出来ません。（タブで表示されます。）

どのようにしたら、別ウィンドウで表示する事が出来ますでしょうか。

※window.openの第3引数にある `menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes` は残したままにしたいです。

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function openWin() {
    window.open(
        "リンク先のURL",
        "_blank",
        "menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=1300,height=1200,top=100,left=100"
    );
}
//-->
</script>

<div style="background-color : #CCC;">
    <input type="button" value="新たにウィンドウを開く" onClick="openWin()">　　
</div>
```

Comment: 基本的には新しいウインドウを開くこと強制することはお勧めされません。参考 [window.open() への依存の回避](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/open#avoid_resorting_to_window.open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Issue 82522: No way to open a pop-up with the toolbar displayed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82522) - bugs.chromium.org

によると、 `toolbar=yes` の設定を保ったまま新しいウィンドウで開くことはできなさそうです。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。ご連絡いただきました内容に該当しております。１０年間も問題が改善されないので、今後も改善されないという意識で対応します。ありがとうございました。